# Loading tiff files into HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, tiff

I am trying to load .tif files onto an HTML5 canvas.  After some research, I discovered that I might be able to do it using FileReader.  Most of my code below is from http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/05/15/working-with-files-in-javascript-part-2/ . Unfortunately, the following test page fails on .tif files (it works on other image files) saying 'Image could not load' in Firefox and Chrome (let's ignore IE for this test).  Am I missing something?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="file" onchange="loadFile(event)"><br>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="100" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000; margin:10px"></canvas>
    <script>
    function loadFile(e) {
      var file = e.target.files[0];

      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(event) {
          var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
          var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
          var dataUri = event.target.result,
              img = new Image();

          // wait until the image has been fully processed
          img.onload = function() {
               context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
          };
          img.onerror = function () {
               console.error('Image could not load.');
          }
          img.src = dataUri;
      };

      reader.onerror = function(event) {
          console.error("File could not be read. Code " + event.target.error.code);
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, you're not missing anything. Chrome & Firefox haven't yet implemented support for drawing .tif images. But, I just Googled this script which displays TIFF on html canvas. :-)

Comment: Chuckle! Here's the link I forgot in my previous comment:https://github.com/seikichi/tiff.js